# Is GitHub working for you right now or is it an OS X 10.7 Firefox browser issue?

Tags: macos, email, firefox, git

**EDIT**: To quickly answer my question, see the bottom edit.

I forgot my GitHub account, so I tried reset my password. However, I'm not receiving any email. I tried it again, but to no avail.

So I thought I'd create a new GitHub account...

I'm at https://github.com/join, filling out username, email, and password. However, under the heading **Verify Account** this [gif](https://github.githubassets.com/images/spinners/octocat-spinner-128.gif) is just looping. I imagine a reCAPTCHA should load...right?

GitHub is displaying this message on the webpage:

`Please note that GitHub no longer supports old versions of Firefox.`

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) with the most up-to-date version of Firefox that it can run.

Question: Is this a Firefox/10.7 Lion issue or an issue with GitHub at this point in time?

**EDIT**: A simple litmus test to **definitively** answer my question would be to do one (or both of the following):

1) Go to https://github.com/password_reset and see if you receive an email (I did not) It won't reset as long as you don't click the email.

2) Go to https://github.com/join and see if the [loading gif](https://github.githubassets.com/images/spinners/octocat-spinner-128.gif) under the heading **Verify Account** changes to something else.

Comment: As the message says "GitHub no longer supports old versions of Firefox", so get a newer browser version. The rest of your question seems to be rather off-topic for AD (it's primarily a Github question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an issue with OS X 10.7 in the sense that this operating system is very old and (most importantly) unsupported.

As it is unsupported, Mozilla have decided not to support recent versions of Firefox on this OS. This is similar to decisions taken by Google and Apple and other browser vendors.

As GitHub requires newer Firefox, and newer Firefox requires newer OS X - you're basically stuck. You should update OS X to continue - or if you cannot do that, then upgrade the hardware or use a different operating system.

You never want to be using an operating system that went out of support years ago (in this case October 2014). The security risk is very high, and logging in to usually sensitive sites such as GitHub should not be done from an unsupported environment.

In regards to your edit, GitHub works fine if you use it with a modern system. It is NOT because GitHub’s join page is broken or down.

Comment: GitHub is now explicitly telling me that I cannot create an account without updating my browser/operating system, rather just that they don't support it (i.e. consider it when testing their code before updating their website code). To answer my question, could you do one of two things (or better, both):  1) Go to https://github.com/password_reset and see if you actually receive an email (I did not receive one). 2) Got to https://github.com/join and see if the [https://github.githubassets.com/images/spinners/octocat-spinner-128.gif](loading gif) changes under the subheading **Verify Account**.

Comment: I'd like to correct my above comment :  

GitHub is \***not** explicitly telling me that I cannot create an account...

Comment: I know they’re not explicitly telling you that. But they don’t support your old system, that’s why it’s not working. Don’t worry - it is working for other people that have new browsers. You really really really want to update for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your response and advice